# Is it possible to programmatically set html attr values with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, animation

I want to create "boomerang" animations (chained animations, with the second one returning the selected element[s] to their original values).

If my assumption is correct that the elements' attr values will be seen as their original values (IOW, not updated after being altered by the first jQuery animation), it should be (at least theoretically) possible to set them back programmatically like this (pseudoscript):

```
$('something').animate( { fontSize: 1.5em, other stuff... } ).animate( { fontSize: $('something').attr(fontSize } ) ...
```

Am I dreaming? Another option would be to .AddClass() in a callback function after the initial animation that would set the values back, but I would prefer the other method, if it's possible; setting it back via AddClass() would be very jerky/faster than a speeding bullet and look "stoopid."

Comment: There's a huge difference when it comes to styles and attributes ?

Comment: i would rather store it in a variable and not requesting it inside the animate-animate dont know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fontSize` is a CSS property, not an element attribute that can be set or retrieved with `.attr()`. You can do something like this:

```
$('something').data("fontSize",$('something').css("fontSize"))
              .animate( { fontSize: "1.5em" }, 1000 )
              .animate( { fontSize: $('something').data("fontSize")}, 1000 );
```

...but it's kind of clunky. You might as well just use a local variable to remember the property:

```
var $something = $('something'),
    fontSize = $something.css("fontSize");
$something.animate( { fontSize: "1.5em" }, 1000 )
          .animate( { fontSize: fontSize}, 1000 );
```

Note also that your original code had a syntax error: you need to put the `1.5em` in quotes.

> *"I want to create "boomerang" animations"*

Have you considered just creating a `boomerang` plugin, so that you could say:

```
$('something').boomerang( {fontSize: "1.5em"});
```

Then any clunkiness would be contained inside the plugin where you don't have to see it when you use it...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to read a css-attribute just dont

```
var size = $('something').attr(fontSize };
```

do

```
var size = $('something').css('font-size');

$('#someId').animate({fontSize: size},3000);
```

Comment: So could I "fontSize: fontSize" using that code? I would name the var something different, to avoid confusion...

Comment: no i think it´s more like my edit, but it´s irritating so another edit